# Format multi-lines don't show with @* in Perl

Tags: perl, format

I would like to show this format correctly. I now get everything on one line. I would like to have the outcome on multiple lines printed. Hope somebody can help me out with this.

```
my $name = "Fred Flinstone";
my $address = "Cave Stone Road 345";
my $city = "Cobblestone";
my $state = "Rock";
my $zip = "13131";

print ("<span class='titel'>");

$~ = "MULTILINE";
write;

format MULTILINE =
===============================
| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< |
$name
| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< |
$address
| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<, @< @<<<< |
$city,           $state, $zip
===============================
@*
.


print ("</span>");
print ("<br><br>");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `\n` symbols, which means 'End of the line':

```
my $name = "Fred Flinstone";
my $address = "Cave Stone Road 345";
my $city = "Cobblestone";
my $state = "Rock";
my $zip = "13131";

print ("<span class='titel'>\n");

$~ = "MULTILINE";
write;

format MULTILINE =
===============================
| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< |
$name
| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< |
$address
| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<, @< @<<<< |
$city,           $state, $zip
===============================
@*
.
print ("</span>\n");
print ("<br><br>\n");
```

Will return:

```
<span class='titel'>
===============================
| Fred Flinstone              |
| Cave Stone Road 345         |
| Cobblestone      , Ro 13131 |
===============================

</span>
<br><br>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I discovered that the html code I had above this script made the code return on one line. xd

Comment: If my answer helped you, I will be appreciated if you will accept it :)

Comment: It was the code above this script what messed it up. Do you know how to prevent earlier html code to mess up with this part of code? I'm totaly new with perl and try to understand why my code didn't display correct

Comment: I don't understand you. It is not messed, they are on different lines. Or there is another HTML code? (Honestly, I nearly don't know Perl, I use my Python background for it :) )

Comment: Ah ok. I hade some other exercises I made before above this script. After putting the code in a new file without the previous exercises, the code worked perfectly, except for the thing you mentioned in your answer. ;-) I just started learning perl so everything is new to me. ;-)

Comment: I read somewhere I have to start a new CGI, but don't know how haha

Comment: Maybe I better change my nickname to perldummy haha

Comment: Note that there's a module called Perl6::Form (Perl6-style forms for Perl5) that's generally preferred over the builtin forms.